# What are Queen's Orders for?

Tags: destiny

So I completed a Queen's bounty from the bounty chap in Tower, only a simple collect 200 items from dead Fallen.

Now I have a new Mission item and I'm not sure what it's for or if I need to redeem it somehow. I tried speaking to the Queen's Wrath NPC, but she didn't want to chat.

[image: Queen's Wrath - Queen's Orders]

Comment: I believe these are a form of currency (like the Vanguard Marks) to be used with the Queen's Emissary. I have so far accrued 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are used to get Legendary armor from the event.  If you have one of these in your inventory and complete a Queen's Wrath: Kill Order mission, you'll get a piece of Legendary Armor.  You can repeat this for each Queen's Orders you have.

This information derived from [Queen's Wrath](http://www.vg247.com/2014/09/24/destiny-legendary-gear-on-offer-in-queens-wrath-event/)

Comment: As a solo player, you can only attempt a Kill Order mission if you have a Queen's Orders in your inventory. The option will be greyed out otherwise. You can get to the missions on the left hand side of the "Set Destination" menu. It is above the daily Crucible icon.

Comment: If you don't have this but you're in a team where the fireteam leader has it, you can do the mission with them but you will not get the legendary equipment reward. Found this out the hard way tonight when a friend didn't understand what "Do you have the Queen's Wrath order?" meant...